# Android Camera : Does OS deletes empty file?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html gives a good way of capturing image from camera.

But as per the tutorial it creates a empty file in "external"(can be user defined) location and what if user cancels activity then empty file will still be there. Is this empty file deletion should be taken care by app itself ? or is there a way by which OS can take care (assuming that location is accessible by OS) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this empty file deletion should be taken care by app itself ?

Yes.

> or is there a way by which OS can take care (assuming that location is accessible by OS) ?

Android has no way to know that you want the file to be deleted, unless you delete the file.

Comment: OS can delete empty file by simply checking file size (Assumption : OS has access to that location )

Comment: @avenger: Just because a file is empty does not mean that the file should not exist. Android is not going to get rid of random files that happen to have zero-byte lengths. Note that while the example happens to create a zero-byte file, that is not required by `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, as [this sample app demonstrates](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content). If you do not want a zero-byte file, do not create it.